# Webpack split vendors per entry point

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have 3 entry points, one of them uses only 2 node modules but it loads all of the other node modules for some reason anyway.

webpack config is:

```js
const plugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks: ['login'],
    base: '/enter',
    filename: 'index-login.html',
    hash: true,
    ...htmlMinifyOptions,
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks: ['app', 'vendor'],
    base: '/admin',
    filename: 'index-admin.html',
    hash: true,
    ...htmlMinifyOptions,
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    chunks: ['landing'],
    base: '/',
    filename: 'index-landing.html',
    hash: true,
    ...htmlMinifyOptions,
  }),
  new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/images'),
        to: 'images',
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ['**/.gitkeep'],
        },
      },
      { from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/favicon.png') },
      { from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/favicon.ico') },
    ]
  }),
  new WebpackManifestPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
]

module.exports.webpack = {
  mode: isProdBuild ? 'production' : 'development',
  // devtool: 'eval',
  target: ['web', 'es5'],
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/js'),
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        reactVendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          reuseExistingChunk: false,
        },
      },
      minSize: 8000,
      maxSize: 12000,
    },
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['./app/index.jsx', hotMiddlewareScript],
    landing: ['./landing/index.jsx', hotMiddlewareScript],
    login: ['./login/index.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/assets'),
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins
}
```